# How to use PIVOT to separate values into different columns without duplication or NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I currently have the three tables below:

Table **#Name**

```
Name_id     NameValue
==========  =============
50          Hannah
51          Jeremy
52          Luna
```

Table **#AttValue**

```
Name_id  AttributeValue_id  AttributeValue
=======  =================  =============
50       11                 01216892584
50       12                 26
50       13                 Female
```

Table **#Attribute**

```
AttributeValue_id  AttributeName
=================  =============
11                 Phone Number
12                 Age
13                 Gender
```

What I want to do is combine them into one and this is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT NameValue,
case when AttributeName = 'Phone Number' then AttributeValue end PhoneNumber
,case when AttributeName = 'Age' then AttributeValue end Age
,case when AttributeName = 'Gender' then AttributeValue end Gender
FROM #Name A
INNER JOIN #AttValue B ON A.Name_id = B.Name_id
INNER JOIN #Attribute C ON B.AttributeValue_id = C.AttributeValue_id
```

This works fine however it results in multiple NameValues and NULL values which I am looking to avoid:

```
NameValue  PhoneNumber  Age  Gender
=========  ============  ===  ======
Hannah     01216892584   NULL NULL
Hannah     NULL          26   NULL
Hannah     NULL          NULL Female
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
NameValue  PhoneNumber  Age  Gender
=========  ===========  ===  ======
Hannah     01216892584  26   Female
```

I understand you can use PIVOT for this, however I struggle to figure out how to do it exactly.

Comment: Oh, the ABCs, [please don't do that](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). This is particularly bad because you've given #Name the alias A yet you have _two other tables in the query_ with names that start with A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Name_id, AttributeValue_id` is a key (e.g. you don't have cases where a person might have two values for `PhoneNumber` - or those cases exist but you don't care which one you get), the simplest way is to just wrap your `CASE` expressions with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  N.NameValue,
  PhoneNumber = MAX(case when A.AttributeName = 'Phone Number' 
                THEN AV.AttributeValue end),
  Age         = MAX(case when A.AttributeName = 'Age' 
                THEN AV.AttributeValue end),
  Gender      = MAX(case when A.AttributeName = 'Gender' 
                THEN AV.AttributeValue end)
FROM #Name AS N
INNER JOIN #AttValue AS AV ON N.Name_id = AV.Name_id
INNER JOIN #Attribute AS A ON AV.AttributeValue_id = A.AttributeValue_id
GROUP BY N.NameValue;
```

Or a PIVOT:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT N.NameValue, A.AttributeName, AV.AttributeValue
    FROM #Name AS N
    INNER JOIN #AttValue AS AV ON N.Name_id = AV.Name_id
    INNER JOIN #Attribute AS A ON AV.AttributeValue_id = A.AttributeValue_id
)
SELECT 
  p.NameValue, 
  PhoneNumber = p.[Phone Number],
  p.Age, 
  p.Gender
FROM src PIVOT (MAX(AttributeValue)
  FOR AttributeName IN ([Phone Number], [Age], [Gender])) AS p;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2afe35f26a34a985d3459eeb19da77b6)

Answer (score 1):

A ***slightly*** different approach using a `UNION ALL` and then `PIVOT`

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select ID    = Name_ID
              ,Item  = 'Name'
              ,Value = NameValue
         From #Name
        Union All
        Select ID    = Name_ID
              ,Item  = A.AttributeName
              ,Value = V.AttributeValue
         From  #Attribute A
         Join  #AttValue  V on A.AttributeValue_ID = V.AttributeValue_ID
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Value) for Item in ([Name],[Phone Number],[Age],[Gender] ) ) Pvt
```

**Results**

[image]

If it helps with the visualization, the UNION ALL looks like this

[image]